# Read/write from file descriptor at offset

Tags: c, file-descriptor

I've been using the [read(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) and [write(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) functions to read and write to a file given a file descriptor.

Is there any function like this that allows you to put an offset into the file for read/write?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for `lseek`.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek

Comment: What exactly does "whence" do? I'm a bit confused by its use of the words "holes" and "data". Is data non-zero values and holes zero values?

Comment: The `whence` governs what the offset is relative to.  So if you ask for 10 bytes with `SEEK_SET`, it will be 10 bytes from the beginning of the file.  If you then ask for 6 bytes with `SEEK_CUR`, it will be 16 bytes from the beginning of the file.

Comment: Don't worry about the gaps and holes.  That's dealing with the situation where you seek past the end of a file.

Answer (score 30):

There are [pread/pwrite](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html) functions that accept file offset:

```
ssize_t pread(int fd, void *buf, size_t count, off_t offset);
ssize_t pwrite(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count, off_t offset);
```

Comment: +1 for this answer. For multi-threaded programs, `pread()` and `pwrite()` are better, because they don't affect the file offset (so multiple threads can read from the same file descriptor without any locking and without race conditions between `lseek()` and `read()`).

Comment: Also only 1 system call!

Comment: This is the better answer IMO.

Answer (score 16):

Yes. You use the `lseek`  function in [the same library](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek).

You can then seek to any offset relative to the start or end of file, or relative to the current location.

Don't get overwhelmed by that library page.  Here are some simple usage examples and probably all most people will ever need:

```
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);   /* seek to start of file */
lseek(fd, 100, SEEK_SET); /* seek to offset 100 from the start */
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);   /* seek to end of file (i.e. immediately after the last byte) */
lseek(fd, -1, SEEK_END);  /* seek to the last byte of the file */
lseek(fd, -10, SEEK_CUR); /* seek 10 bytes back from your current position in the file */
lseek(fd, 10, SEEK_CUR);  /* seek 10 bytes ahead of your current position in the file */
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

[`lseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lseek.html) and ye shall  receive.

Comment: I thought it was `lseek` and ye shall `lfind`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [`lseek()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek):

```
off_t lseek(int fd, off_t offset, int whence);
```

> The `lseek()` function repositions the offset of the open file associated with the file descriptor `fd` to the argument `offse`t according to the directive `whence` as follows:
>
> `SEEK_SET`
>
> The offset is set to offset bytes.
>
> `SEEK_CUR`
>
> The offset is set to its current location plus offset bytes.
>
> `SEEK_END`
>
> The offset is set to the size of the file plus offset bytes.