# C how to pass pointer to location in file for reading

Tags: c, file, pointers

If have a given file
Ex:

```
abc def ghijk
```

And want to pass a pointer for the file to a function ex:

```
void myfunc(FILE * myfile)
```

How can I have the pointer in the file not point to the first char (in this case a) but instead to the first char after two spaces (in this case g)? For example id pass:

```
myfunc(myfile.charat(9)) //or something
```

then in myfunc() the first getc call would return 'g'.

Comment: Do you know the location of "the first char after two spaces" before you open the file? If you do, try [fseek()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/)

Comment: No, however, I could loop through the file once, find the location then reload the file. So for all intensive purposes, yes.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic or rather, "how do you know...".. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read/write from file descriptor at offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780919/read-write-from-file-descriptor-at-offset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion will be to read and discard characters until you have encountered two space characters.

Write a function for that:

```
void skipUntilTwoSpaces(FILE* in)
{
   int count = 2;
   int c;
   while ( count > 0 && (c = getc(in)) != EOF) )
   {
      if ( c == ' ')
      {
         --count;
      }
   }
}
```

and use it where it makes most sense in your code.

Comment: I believe this is the better solution as it clears up some confusion for me on the FILE internal pointer to the file location. When FILE is passed the file location value is still up to date so there's no need for an fseek or lseek.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the function [`fseek()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek). Just write

```
fseek(myfile, 9, SEEK_SET);
```

before passing `myfile` to your function. You might want to check the return value, so you know whether setting the position succeeded.

---

Btw, don't confuse the "file position indicator" (sometimes called "file pointer") with the "pointer to a `FILE`". They are different things. The file position indicator is stored somewhere internally in `FILE` (or, more likely, in some operating-system object associated with the `FILE`) to know what position in the file to read or write next. `FILE *` on the other hand is the memory location of your (stdio-internal) `FILE` structure.